# How to change photo sharing settings on Google+ (For photos uploaded from Mobile)

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I have uploaded one photo from Google+ application on my Android phone. Although I am pretty sure that I have selected only one Circle while uploading but may be due to some bug it is visible to all Circles. Now I want to change sharing settings for this photo but I could not find this option anywhere. Can anybody help?

Comment: I have added (For Photos uploaded from Mobile) as Barry has answered how to change settings for Photos uploaded from the web application

Comment: Since you're asking about the Android app, this question really should be at [android.se].

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by:

- Logging in to Google+
- Selecting the `Photos` sections

[image: Google+ Photos]

- Select `Your albums`

[image: Google+ Your Albums]

- Select the album which your picture is in
- At the top left of the picture there will be an `Edit` link
  [image: Google+ Edit Photo]
- Click the `Edit` link and a popup will appear where you check/amend the visibility.
  [image: Google+ Edit Photo Sharing Options]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But I could see only this "Visible to: Recipients of the original posts" without any edit button. May be due to these photos are uploaded from Mobile App.

Comment: @Deependra Solanky: I haven't tested it but that would indicate you would have to go to your posts and edit the visibility of the post rather than the photo? I *think* that is how it works for photos uploaded via mobile.

Comment: I have also thought the same but could not find a option to edit visibility of post. My bad..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same thing. It seems you may only be able to alter the visibility with a Windows PC. Seems there is no way of doing it with Android.